# How to pass through form filling with web-scratching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, request-promise

How to pass through website login form and see HTML code of any related webpages on website.

I trying to pass through login form on the website and then parse html page where holding my account info, but I can't do this. 
Here is my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs'); //access to file system
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');
const app = express();

let url = 'url';

(request.post({url:'url1', form: {
    email:'email',
    password:'password'  
}}, 
function(error, response, html){
    if(error){
    console.log(error);
    }
    else{
    console.log(html);
    }
}))

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
    requestToWork(url);
    res.send('Check your console!')
})

function requestToWork(url){
    return rp(url)
    .then(HTMLresponse=>{ 
        const $ = cheerio.load(HTMLresponse);
        console.log($.text());
        $('.ellipsis').each((i, element) => {
            console.log(element);
        });
    })
}

app.listen('8080')
console.log('Listening port 8080');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

It just logs to me HTML code from LOGIN page. I want to log another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, `cheerio` can't follow new url.
In your particular case, there is two possible solutions:

1. Login on site with your browser, access cookies via developer tools and copy them to your `request`. Something like this from [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestcookie).
2. Use automated headless browser, which can follow page redirect. And keep your session data. Like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

If you already using node.js, it would be easier to implement logic with puppeteer.

[Here](https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial) is more information on puppeteer.

**Update**

Puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  // Now you have two ways
  // First one with evaluate, to access page DOM
  await page.evaluate(() => {
     // Here you have access to DOM. So you can make any JS DOM operations, you wish.

     const form = document.querySelector('form');
     const email = document.querySelector('email'); 

     // ...some actions

     form.submit();
  })

  // The second one, with puppeteer helper functions
  const email = await page.$('email');
  // Type function will type text in input
  await elementHandle.type('some text');
  // press function will emulate enter button press.
  await elementHandle.press('Enter');

  await page.waitFor(1500);
  // Here you have result of your auth procedure.

  // After all your operations, just close the browser.
  await browser.close();
})();
```

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options) is about puppeteer type

If we're looking for `request` implementation.
First, we have to get the cookie.
You can extract cookies via [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) chrome extension, or go to development tools, `Network` tab, click on first record and look for `Cookie` header in `Request Headers` section.

Just copy it
And then, in code you execute `request` like this from [official documentation](https://github.com/request/request):

```
const j = request.jar();
// Here 'key1=value1' change with your cookie from browser
const cookie = request.cookie('key1=value1');
const url = 'http://www.google.com';
j.setCookie(cookie, url);
request({url: url, jar: j}, function () {
    request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

Comment: Can you give me some simple example like link to github repo?

Comment: @VladSymonenko for which solution? using cookies or `puppeteer`?

Comment: Both of them if you can.